# Setting paypal client id on Javascript script tag on user browser using frontend technology. is it safe

Tags: javascript, paypal

Paypal javascript sdk recommends setting client id on script tag

```
<script> src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&components=YOUR_COMPONENTS"></script>
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/

Answer (score 0):

A client ID is required for using the JavaScript SDK, which operates on the client side.

If you want to [do things on a server](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls) ('Capture Order' and 'Create Order'), you'll need to make use of REST APIs, which use a client id + secret.

See this demo pattern for connecting the JS SDK to a server: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server